# Symfony 3.4.3 - service container: Error requires that you provide a value for the

Tags: php, forms, dependency-injection, dto, symfony-3.4

i spent a lot of time but i did not solve it
I would like to pass LoggerInterface in the action of my controller

here is my service.yml

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # AppBundle\Controller\ArticlesController:
    appbundle.form.type.articles:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\ArticlesController 
        autowire: false
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

here is my controller

```
<?php
//AppBundle\Controller\ArticlesController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Dto\ArticlesRequest; 
use AppBundle\Form\ArticlesType;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface; 



class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    public function ListAction()
    {
        return $this->render("@App/Articles/list.html.twig");
    }

    public function CreateAction(Request $request, LoggerInterface $logger) 
    {
        $createArticleRequest = new ArticlesRequest();

        $form = $this->createForm(ArticlesType::class, $createArticleRequest); 
        return $this->render("@App/Articles/create.html.twig", array('form' => $form->createView()));
        //return $this->render("@App/Articles/create.html.twig");

    }

    public function EditAction()
    {
        return $this->render("@App/Articles/edit.html.twig");
    }

    public function DeleteAction()
    {
        return $this->render("@App/Articles/delete.html.twig");
    }

}
```

This is the error message:

*Controller "AppBundle\Controller\ArticlesController::CreateAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$logger" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.*

Answer (score 1):

In your services.yml under appbundle.form.type.articles, you need to pass autowire to true. Otherwise symfony cannot inject the dependencies in your service.
If you add a null default value as suggested above, you will not be able to log anything since you cannot log into a null. And if you do not want to log anything, simply remove the LoggerInterface from your parameters.

Answer (score -1):

i resolve whit this code

instead of

```
public function CreateAction(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $logger)
```

this

```
public function CreateAction(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $logger = null)
```

add only = null

Comment: what if the $logger is null , you can't use that anyway in the controller